# How to install CUDA 11 on Ubuntu 18.04 installed on the Jetson nano

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dependencies, cuda

I'm trying to install CUDA 11 on top of ubuntu 18.04 for arm64 on the Jetson nano. This is what happened :

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/sbsa/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin

sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_arm64.deb

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_arm64.deb

sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/7fa2af80.pub

sudo apt-get update

Downloading di:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-l4t-10-2-local  InRelease

Ignored:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-l4t-10-2-local  InRelease

Downloading di:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  InRelease

Ignored:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  InRelease

Downloading di:3 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease

Ignored:3 file:/var/visionworks-repo  InRelease

Downloading di:4 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease

Ignored:4 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  InRelease

Downloading di:5 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease

Ignored:5 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  InRelease

Downloading di:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-l4t-10-2-local  Release [564 B]

Downloading di:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  Release [564 B]

Downloading di:6 file:/var/cuda-repo-l4t-10-2-local  Release [564 B]

Downloading di:8 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [2,001 B]                    

Downloading di:7 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  Release [564 B]                       

Downloading di:8 file:/var/visionworks-repo  Release [2,001 B]                                    

Downloading di:9 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,005 B]                                

Downloading di:9 file:/var/visionworks-sfm-repo  Release [2,005 B]                                

Downloading di:10 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,010 B]                          

Downloading di:10 file:/var/visionworks-tracking-repo  Release [2,010 B]                          

Downloading di:11 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  Release.gpg [836 B]                  

Downloading di:11 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  Release.gpg [836 B]                  

Found:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease                                   

Downloading of:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu bionic InRelease [21.3 kB]

Ignored:16 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-security InRelease                      

Downloading of:18 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.7 InRelease [2,555 B]        

Downloading of:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]         

Downloading of:19 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t210 r32.7 InRelease [2,550 B]          

Ignored:20 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-updates InRelease                       

Downloading of:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease [83.3 kB]       

Ignored:22 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security InRelease                    

Downloading of:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]        

Ignored:23 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates InRelease                     

Error:24 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-security Release 
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]

Error:26 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-updates Release     
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]

Error:27 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security Release  
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]

Error:28 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates Release   
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate chain uses not yet valid certificate.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 185.125.190.24 443]

Downloading di:31 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  Packages [21.9 kB]
Reading packages list... Done                     

E: The repository "https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-security Release" don't have a file Release anymore.

N: Updating from such a repository cannot be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.

E: The repository "https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu bionic-apps-updates Release" don't have a file Release anymore.

N: Updating from such a repository cannot be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.

E: The repository "https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security Release" don't have a file Release anymore.

N: Updating from such a repository cannot be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.

E: The repository "https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates Release" don't have a file Release anymore.

N: Updating from such a repository cannot be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.

E: File Release for http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipewire-debian/pipewire-upstream/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease is not valid yet (non valido per 35g 13h 6min 9s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: File Release for https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common/dists/r32.7/InRelease is not valid yet (non valido per 60g 12h 44min 23s). Updates for Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: File Release for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (non valido per 62g 20h 22min 15s). Updates for Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: File Release for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease is not valid yet (non valido per 62g 19h 46min 21s). Updates for Updates for this repository will not be applied.

E: File Release for http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/bionic-security/InRelease is not valid yet (non valido per 62g 19h 42min 54s). Updates for Updates for this repository will not be applied.

sudo apt-get -y install cuda

Following additional packages will be installed :

  cuda-11-0 cuda-command-line-tools-11-0 cuda-compiler-11-0 cuda-cudart-11-0 cuda-cudart-dev-11-0
  cuda-cuobjdump-11-0 cuda-cupti-11-0 cuda-cupti-dev-11-0 cuda-documentation-11-0
  cuda-driver-dev-11-0 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-450 cuda-gdb-11-0 cuda-libraries-11-0
  cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 cuda-nsight-compute-11-0 cuda-nsight-systems-11-0 cuda-nvcc-11-0
  cuda-nvdisasm-11-0 cuda-nvml-dev-11-0 cuda-nvprof-11-0 cuda-nvprune-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-11-0
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 cuda-nvtx-11-0 cuda-runtime-11-0 cuda-samples-11-0 cuda-sanitizer-11-0
  cuda-toolkit-11-0 cuda-tools-11-0 cuda-visual-tools-11-0 dkms libcublas-11-0 libcublas-dev-11-0
  libcufft-11-0 libcufft-dev-11-0 libcurand-11-0 libcurand-dev-11-0 libcusolver-11-0
  libcusolver-dev-11-0 libcusparse-11-0 libcusparse-dev-11-0 libnpp-11-0 libnpp-dev-11-0
  libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-common-450 libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-decode-450
  libnvidia-encode-450 libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450
  libnvjpeg-11-0 libnvjpeg-dev-11-0 libxnvctrl0 linux-headers-4.15.0-208
  linux-headers-4.15.0-208-generic linux-headers-generic nsight-compute-2020.1.1
  nsight-systems-linux-tegra-public-2021.5.4.19-e642d4b nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-dkms-450
  nvidia-driver-450 nvidia-kernel-common-450 nvidia-kernel-source-450 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-450 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450
I seguenti pacchetti NUOVI saranno installati:
  cuda cuda-11-0 cuda-command-line-tools-11-0 cuda-compiler-11-0 cuda-cudart-11-0
  cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 cuda-cuobjdump-11-0 cuda-cupti-11-0 cuda-cupti-dev-11-0
  cuda-documentation-11-0 cuda-driver-dev-11-0 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-450 cuda-gdb-11-0
  cuda-libraries-11-0 cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 cuda-nsight-compute-11-0 cuda-nsight-systems-11-0
  cuda-nvcc-11-0 cuda-nvdisasm-11-0 cuda-nvml-dev-11-0 cuda-nvprof-11-0 cuda-nvprune-11-0
  cuda-nvrtc-11-0 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 cuda-nvtx-11-0 cuda-runtime-11-0 cuda-samples-11-0
  cuda-sanitizer-11-0 cuda-toolkit-11-0 cuda-tools-11-0 cuda-visual-tools-11-0 dkms libcublas-11-0
  libcublas-dev-11-0 libcufft-11-0 libcufft-dev-11-0 libcurand-11-0 libcurand-dev-11-0
  libcusolver-11-0 libcusolver-dev-11-0 libcusparse-11-0 libcusparse-dev-11-0 libnpp-11-0
  libnpp-dev-11-0 libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-common-450 libnvidia-compute-450
  libnvidia-decode-450 libnvidia-encode-450 libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450
  libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450 libnvjpeg-11-0 libnvjpeg-dev-11-0 libxnvctrl0
  linux-headers-4.15.0-208 linux-headers-4.15.0-208-generic linux-headers-generic
  nsight-compute-2020.1.1 nsight-systems-linux-tegra-public-2021.5.4.19-e642d4b
  nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-driver-450 nvidia-kernel-common-450
  nvidia-kernel-source-450 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-450
  screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450

Downloading:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-cudart-11-0 11.0.194-1 [124 kB]

Downloading:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 dkms all 2.3-3ubuntu9.7 [68.1 kB]

Downloading:3 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvrtc-11-0 11.0.194-1 [5,926 kB]

Downloading:4 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r32.7/main arm64 nsight-systems-linux-tegra-public-2021.5.4.19-e642d4b arm64 2021.5.4.19-e642d4b [67.3 MB]

Downloading:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic/main arm64 screen-resolution-extra all 0.17.3 [11.7 kB]

Downloading:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 linux-headers-4.15.0-208 all 4.15.0-208.220 [11.0 MB]

Downloading:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 linux-headers-4.15.0-208-generic arm64 4.15.0-208.220 [895 kB]

Ignored:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 linux-headers-generic arm64 4.15.0.208.191

Downloading:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 nvidia-prime all 0.8.16~0.18.04.1 [9,224 B]

Error:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates/main arm64 linux-headers-generic arm64 4.15.0.208.191
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]

Downloading:10 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcublas-11-0 11.1.0.229-1 [116 MB]

Downloading:11 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcufft-11-0 10.2.0.218-1 [97.9 MB] 

Downloading:12 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcurand-11-0 10.2.1.218-1 [39.0 MB]

Downloading:13 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcusolver-11-0 10.5.0.218-1 [284 MB]

Downloading:14 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcusparse-11-0 11.1.0.218-1 [72.9 MB]

Downloading:15 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnpp-11-0 11.1.0.218-1 [56.3 MB]   

Downloading:16 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvjpeg-11-0 11.1.0.218-1 [1,275 kB]

Downloading:17 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-libraries-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,490 B]

Downloading:18 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-common-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [10.0 kB]

Downloading:19 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-compute-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [9,231 kB]

Downloading:20 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-decode-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [1,077 kB]

Downloading:21 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-encode-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [39.5 kB]

Downloading:22 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-fbc1-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [7,040 B]

Downloading:23 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-gl-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [54.9 MB]

Downloading:24 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-ifr1-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [7,068 B]

Downloading:25 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-compute-utils-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [109 kB]

Downloading:26 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-kernel-source-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [11.6 MB]

Downloading:27 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-kernel-common-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [9,402 B]

Downloading:28 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-dkms-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [26.7 kB]

Downloading:29 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-extra-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [38.0 kB]

Downloading:30 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-driver-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [411 kB]

Downloading:31 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-utils-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [347 kB]

Downloading:32 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvidia-cfg1-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [74.2 kB]

Downloading:33 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [1,235 kB]

Downloading:34 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-modprobe 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [17.7 kB]

Downloading:35 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libxnvctrl0 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [20.5 kB]

Downloading:36 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nvidia-settings 450.51.05-0ubuntu1 [826 kB]

Downloading:37 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-drivers-450 450.51.05-1 [2,628 B]

Downloading:38 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-drivers 450.51.05-1 [2,504 B]   

Downloading:39 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-runtime-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,426 B] 

Downloading:40 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-cuobjdump-11-0 11.0.194-1 [91.3 kB]

Downloading:41 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-driver-dev-11-0 11.0.194-1 [26.1 kB]

Downloading:42 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-cudart-dev-11-0 11.0.194-1 [1,609 kB]

Downloading:43 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvcc-11-0 11.0.194-1 [15.7 MB]  

Downloading:44 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvprune-11-0 11.0.167-1 [46.5 kB]

Downloading:45 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-compiler-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,422 B]

Downloading:46 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-0 11.0.194-1 [22.0 kB]

Downloading:47 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcublas-dev-11-0 11.1.0.229-1 [118 MB]

Downloading:48 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcufft-dev-11-0 10.2.0.218-1 [176 MB]

Downloading:49 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcurand-dev-11-0 10.2.1.218-1 [39.2 MB]

Downloading:50 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcusolver-dev-11-0 10.5.0.218-1 [17.6 MB]

Downloading:51 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libcusparse-dev-11-0 11.1.0.218-1 [72.8 MB]

Downloading:52 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnpp-dev-11-0 11.1.0.218-1 [57.3 MB]

Downloading:53 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  libnvjpeg-dev-11-0 11.1.0.218-1 [1,243 kB]

Downloading:54 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-libraries-dev-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,514 B]

Downloading:55 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-cupti-11-0 11.0.194-1 [3,551 kB]

Downloading:56 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-cupti-dev-11-0 11.0.194-1 [124 kB]

Downloading:57 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvdisasm-11-0 11.0.194-1 [27.2 MB]

Downloading:58 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-gdb-11-0 11.0.194-1 [2,925 kB]  

Downloading:59 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvprof-11-0 11.0.194-1 [18.0 kB]

Downloading:60 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvtx-11-0 11.0.167-1 [51.8 kB]  

Downloading:61 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-sanitizer-11-0 11.0.194-1 [5,553 kB]

Downloading:62 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-command-line-tools-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,472 B]

Downloading:63 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  nsight-compute-2020.1.1 2020.1.1.8-1 [75.0 MB]

Downloading:64 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nsight-compute-11-0 11.0.2-1 [3,574 B]

Downloading:65 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nsight-systems-11-0 11.0.2-1 [3,284 B]

Downloading:66 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-nvml-dev-11-0 11.0.167-1 [71.9 kB]

Downloading:67 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-visual-tools-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,934 B]

Downloading:68 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-tools-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,382 B]   

Downloading:69 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-samples-11-0 11.0.194-1 [42.3 MB]

Downloading:70 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-documentation-11-0 11.0.207-1 [59.6 MB]

Downloading:71 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-toolkit-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,726 B] 

Downloading:72 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda-11-0 11.0.2-1 [2,440 B]         

Downloading:73 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local  cuda 11.0.2-1 [2,392 B]              

This seems to be the real error :

E: Can't get package from http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/l/linux-meta/linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.208.191_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]

E: Can't get some packages. You need to run "apt-get update" or try option "--fix-missing".
```

Someone knows where I can get that file ? Do you have some suggestion to give to me ? (I tried the option "apt-get update --fix-missing" ; it didn't work,the error is the same. It needs to find and install the package "linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.208.191_arm64.deb",but it cannot be found and the upgrading process stops.

Comment: Bro',nvidia supports only ubuntu 18.04 on the jetson nano. I have installed ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 on the jetson nano,ok ? but actually cuda 10 is installed there. I would like to install cuda 11 and the only way I found is to follow this tutorial : https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/07/29/install-cuda-11-on-jetson-nano-and-xavier-nx/ ; but it requires ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Marietto by "expired" David means that this version of Ubuntu - 18.04 - reaches the end of standard support during May 2023.  Which means after May 2023 you will no longer be able to receive support for it here.

Comment: @David your comments in this case weren't helpful, please be aware you need to be *clear* what you mean in comments.

Comment: @ThomasWard : may is not over,yet.

Comment: You're right, but David was just *suggesting* you go with a release that doesnt go EOSS in less than 3 weeks.  My comment was simply explaining what David meant.

Comment: nvidia supports only ubuntu 18.04 on the jetson nano ; can you suggest to nvidia to support ubuntu 20.04 or more and not to me ? I can't do whatever I want. nvidia can.

Comment: none of us are developers with contacts at nVidia.  You can make that request to nVidia support generally, but none of us can make that recommendation.  *We* are not developers, we're just volunteers.

Answer (score 0):

4.15.0.208.191 is an obsolete kernel (meta) package version, no longer available in the repo. Your steps seem to want to pull in header packages probably for all installed kernels. Update your system, specifically the kernel, and remove unused/obsolete kernel packages.

I was able to install CUDA 11 on an updated 18.04 system using your steps.

Comment: It seems CUDA 12 is available for 20.04 on the jetson: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=aarch64-jetson&Compilation=Native&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04

Comment: I can't upgrade ubuntu 18.04 ; nvidia supports only ubuntu 18.04 on the jetson nano. In addition,that cuda version (11) is supposed to work only on the 18.04. I tried to install it on ubuntu 20.04 ; it didn't work. Cuda 12 is not supposed to work on the jetson nano because it is not supported. Ubuntu 20.04 is not supported on the jetson nano. The only hope I have is to find the missing file and try to complete the installation on ubuntu 18.04. Is there a place where I can grab it ?

Comment: By upgrade I mean upgrade the 18.04 packages, not upgrade to a later series. It seems you have old and unsupported kernels installed and the CUDA installation process pulls in header packages for all installed kernels but header packages for old kernels are no longer available from the archive. You need to manually remove these old kernel packages.